Is "outside of" grammatical?

I live in Connecticut outside of NYC.

Are both outside and of prepositions? Can two prepositions be used together?
How is it compared to just outside?

I live in Connecticut outside NYC.


See this question on English Language and Usage - it's grammatical, but mainly north American, and some people don't like it. It's certainly possible to have multiple prepositions together; some such things are controversial ("off of"), others are universally fine ("go round to my parents", "go up into space").

Arguably neither go round to nor go up into contains two prepositions: round and up can be adverbs, or (in the first case particularly) go round could be a phrasal verb.
But I agree with your comment nonetheless.

Similar:  abreast of, on top of, downwind of, upstream of.

Also: off of, inside of

@TimR Is any of abreast, top, downwind and upstream a preposition?

@Tim  You'd have to ask someone who specializes in that sort of thing. It's certainly possible to understand how words work without putting the word into a category.

I add to what @Stuart F has commented.
Both outside and of are prepositions.
The resultant preposition outside of means outside in this context.
Google has a similar definition:

beyond the boundaries of

The OP’s two examples mean the same, but the version with of is more likely AmE.
Edit to Answer the OP’s Further Queries
The Ngram graphs show the ten most common double prepositions ending with of The most frequently used are out of and because of; as of is a distant third, with the rest collapsing at the bottom of the frequency chart. It is not practical to compile a list to cover the rest of the prepositions.  We should check before attempting to use rare pairs.

thanks. which preps can "of" follow, and which not?

Hi, @Tim,  I've added more information to my answer.

Is out in out of an adverb?

Yes, it's grammatically acceptable and pretty common. Though the rules of grammar might tell you that two prepositions are incorrect together, this really functions as a compound preposition. We use it to specify that something is just beyond the boundaries or limits of something.
It may well have entered speech because 'outside' is also a noun and requires the additional preposition, for example:

"I'm cleaning outside the house" could mean you're sweeping the yard
"I'm cleaning the outside of the house" could mean you're cleaning the exterior brickwork, for example.

There are also contexts where it just feels right to use "outside of", even if there is no right or wrong. I hear "outside of work hours" quite often, and I suppose "outside work hours" could be considered an ambiguity because "outside work" is sometimes used as a noun phrase for work that takes place outdoors.
